# How to create a lambda for assignment?

Tags: python

I just to pass something like:

```
def ___(x):
    x.a=0
    return x
```

or

```
def ___(x):
    x.a=0
```

into a function. How to make it happen?

Comment: How do you make what happen exactly? I'm not sure what you're really trying to achieve here...

Comment: if thats all you are doing wouldnt it be better to just do it? instead of obscuring the setting of a attribute in some method (maybe your example is overly simplified and you are doing more than just setting an attribute)

Answer (score 2):

A lambda can only be an expression, and assignment isn't an expression in Python. Fortunately, there is another way to set an attribute in Python: the function `setattr()`. So you can write:

```
lambda x: setattr(x, "a", 0)
```

This isn't very good Python, though, because it makes the code less clear just so it can be used in a lambda. I'd just use a named function.

Comment: I'd just make the assignment rather than call a function (of any kind) to do it.

Comment: Presumably it's being passed to some other function as a callback. Otherwise, I agree.

Comment: Of course, but the context is pretty thin here...not unlike certain kinds of pancakes. `;-)`